# How to ignore SSL-Certificate with HTTPS Health Check

Tags: ssl, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am setting up a Health Check in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure for DNS failover. The destiation is only reachable through HTTPS and has a valid SSL-Certificate for the domain name. However, when activating the health check, it always fails with error message:

```
x509: cannot validate certificate for x.x.x.x because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

I tried to set the domain name in the HTTP header host field. However, this does not seem to help in the SSL authentication.

Is there a way to ignore SSL errors for the health check? Or do I somehow need to include all IP addresses in the SSL certificate? I would like to avoid having to get a new signed SSL certificate each time an IP address changes or is added.

Comment: You are trying to reach the resource by IP address (in the URL) instead of an hostname. Reach it with an hostname and it will work as the certificate is for an hostname and not an IP address, which is what the error message tells you. "I would like to avoid having to get a new signed SSL certificate each time an IP address changes or is added." Which is exactly why you should use hostnames...

Comment: "Is there a way to ignore SSL errors for the health check?" Whatever the problem is, this is certainly always not the good direction to go.

Comment: "I tried to set the domain name in the HTTP header host field. However, this does not seem to help in the SSL authentication." TLS handshake happens before any kind of HTTP exchange, so nothing at the HTTP level can influence the result of the TLS handshake. The client sends the host (and that can be a name or an IP address depending on what you put in the URL, which will also be the thing later in the HTTP `host` header) it wants to reach through the TLS SNI extension, and it gets back a certificate. It (the client) then makes sure the certificate matches the name/IP used.